# Javascript: Difference between location.hostname and document.domain?

Tags: javascript, dns, hostname

What is the difference between using location.hostname and document.domain?

I think an explanation with an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that `document.domain` is a *read only* property, except in Mozilla, which lets you change the value of the domain that is used for the same origin policy of (for example) AJAX requests without actually updating the page.

The restrictions on this are the same rules of the Same Origin Policy.

At least this is my understanding of the [MDC docs for `document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain).

**From the docs:**

> Gets/sets the domain portion of the origin of the current document, as used by the same origin policy.
>
> ...
>
> In the DOM HTML specification, this property is listed as being read-only. However, Mozilla will let you set it to a superdomain of the current value, constrained by its base domain. For example, on developer.mozilla.org it is possible to set it to "mozilla.org" but not "mozilla.com" or "org".

Try updating `document.domain` and `window.location.hostname` to a new value in the console, and see the difference.

Comment: Seems that it is useful in Safari/Chrome/Firefox (haven't tested in IE  or Opera yet). You can basically reduce a sub-domain to one of its super-domains (except for the TLD) for purposes affected by Same Origin Policy. It does not change the location of the page itself.

Comment: That's exactly what it's for. It's only useful when you change it.

Comment: @Tim: This one was new to me. Do you happen to know off hand if it is well supported in IE as a non ready-only property? Otherwise, I'll fire up VMWare in a bit and test it.

Comment: Yes, it's supported non-read-only in IE, since version 4 I think.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks much! Saved me the trouble. Much appreciated.